# Determine if duplicate string follows

Tags: perl

How can I determine if a duplicate string follows string A.
For example: Stack Overflow,Stack would be true where as Hello World,Random wouldn't.

I have tried:

```
use strict;
my @strings = ("Hello World, Hello", "How are you, are");
foreach my $duplicate (@strings) {
   my @split = split(/,/, $duplicate);

   my $a = @split[0];
   my $b = @split[1];    
   if ($a =~ m/$b/) {
          print "Duplicate\n";
       } else {
          print "True\n";
       }
}
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Daveid: Post what you have tried and the output.

Comment: What should be returned for "Stack Overflow,StackTrace"? That is, how do you define a duplicate string?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regular expression:

```
/(.+).*\1/
```

But notice that even a space can be the repeated string. Also, anything can precede and follow the string and its repetition. You might need to adjust the expression to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Your script works not so bad, just change the split this way:

```
my @split = split(/\s*,\s*/, $duplicate);
```